# delete string in a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a

```
df =  pandasdataframe with data.
```

I have a second pandas-dataframe (called df_outlier) with only some keys (that obviously also exist in df) and I want to remove them from df.

```
df_outlier
```

I was looking for something like the following function - but that might not be the right approach. The key contains alphanumeric values - so letters and numbers. So it is not an int.

```
clean_df = (df['ID'] - df_outlier['ID'])
```

Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: Sorry are you looking for `clean_df = df[~df['ID'].isin(df_outlier['ID'])]`?

Comment: Well I want to remove the IDs from df_outlier in df.

Comment: Well have you tried my code snippet? it will remove all rows from the df that contain ids in df_outlier

Comment: Thanks EdChum - you are right - it works. can we turn it into an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To filter a df using multiple values from another df we can use [`isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.isin.html#pandas.Series.isin), this will return a boolean mask for the rows where the values exist in the passed in list/Series. In order to filter out these values we use the negation operator `~` to invert the mask:

```
clean_df = df[~df['ID'].isin(df_outlier['ID'])]
```